How do I secure loose j channel around windows?
Our inspector recommended we secure the loose j-channel around our window. I’ve researched and can’t find out how to secure this. I am thinking after watching videos on how to install, that I just need to pull back the j channel a bit and nail it back. Any other better ideas on this? Our house has existing wood (or other material?) siding under it which was covered with this vinyl. 

Do you see any wood behind the J-channel?  Siding being siding, it looks like the section above the window is on a different plane from the plane near the light. It it was the window, you'd have problems opening it.
